# Request.QueryString is undefined

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net

i am using the following code to get `LogedInUser` from `LogIn.aspx` and send it to `Chat.aspx` then send it  to `FrmForAjaxCalls` to return data from Db and fill it on div  but in running time it telling me in browser console 
 request.querystring is undefined

here is `LogIn.aspx` code

```
protected void Button3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

    Response.Redirect("Chat.aspx?LGN2="+TextBoxUserName.Text);
}
```

and this is `Chat.aspx` javascript code

```
<script type="text/javascript" >
    var xmlhttp;

    function GetData() {
        xmlhttp = null;
        if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
            xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
        }
        else if (window.ActiveXObject) {
            xmlhttp = new ActiveXObject();
        }
                  string LogedInUser = Request.Cookies["LogedInUser"].Value;


        var LogedInUser = Request.QueryString["LGN2"];

        xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function () {

            if (xmlhttp.readystate == 4 || xmlhttp.status == 200) {

                document.getElementById("MyDiv").innerHTML = xmlhttp.responseText;
            }
        }
        xmlhttp.open("GET", "FrmForAjaxCalls.aspx?LGN=" + LogedInUser, true);
        xmlhttp.send();
    }
```

then i send it to `FrmForAjaxCalls` to return data but its return nothing on the div with `Request.QueryString` is undefined exption on browser console

```
 protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string LogedInUser = Request.QueryString["LGN2"].ToString();

    StringBuilder html = new StringBuilder();

        String result = String.Empty;
        SqlConnection cnn = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["CRConnection"].ConnectionString);
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("Select MessageNum , Message , SenderName ,Date from Message where ReciverUserName='" + LogedInUser + "'", cnn);
        cnn.Open();
        SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        da.Fill(dt);
        html.Append("<div id = xxx> ");
        html.Append("<table border='1'>");
        html.Append("<tr>");
        foreach (DataColumn col in dt.Columns)
        {
            html.Append("<th>");
            html.Append(col.ColumnName);
            html.Append("</th>");
        }
        html.Append("</tr>");
        foreach (DataRow row in dt.Rows)
        {
            html.Append("<tr>");
            foreach (DataColumn col in dt.Columns)
            {
                html.Append("<td>");
                html.Append(row[col.ColumnName]);
                html.Append("</td>");
            }
            html.Append("</tr>");
        }
        html.Append("</table>");
        html.Append("</div>");

        Response.Write(html);

}
```

Answer (score 1):

In your paste for `Chat.aspx`, you're calling it `LGN` instead of `LGN2`... Could that be all?  In situations like this, your first mission should be to add logging throughout the process to see where it falls apart, so you can pinpoint where the problem is.

Comment: its the same 
by the way LogedInUser is sent from Login.aspx to Chat.aspx 

but not sent from Chat.aspx to FrmForAjaxCalls.aspx

Comment: Look at the code.  You're setting LGN= in the call to FrmForAjax, but looking for LGN2 once you get there.

Comment: Then start logging things, check the network console in the browser... find out where it's falling off.  You have to learn to troubleshoot.